# Contour Integral using Cauchy's integral formula

Tags: complex-analysis, cauchy-integral-formula

$$I = \oint_C\frac{\sin(\pi z)}{(z-1)^5}\,dz,\quad\text{$C$ is the circle $|z|=2$.}$$

I have that there is a singularity at $z = 1$. So, taking $z_0 = 1$ we can write

$$I = \oint_C\frac{f(z)}{(z-z_0)^5}\,dz\quad\text{where $f(z)=\sin(\pi z)$}\Rightarrow f^{(4)}(z) = \pi^4\sin(\pi z)$$

Using this derivative theorem in my notes that looks like this:

$$f^{(n)}(z_0) = \frac{n!}{2\pi i}\oint_C\frac{f(z)}{(z-z_0)^{n+1}}\,dz$$

I can write

$$I = \frac{2\pi i}{4!}\cdot f^{(4)}(1) = \frac{2\pi i}{4!}\cdot(0) = 0$$

Is this final answer of zero correct?

Comment: Yes, since the power expansion of the sine has no even power terms.

Comment: Isn't one order of the denominator removable? So isn't the residue just of order $4$? Or am I remembering incorrectly?

Comment: okay, so what do I do if $C$ is the circle $|z| = \frac{1}{2}$ because then there are no singularities inside $C$.

Comment: Then your answer is zero because $C$ is a closed curve containing no singularities.

Comment: @The zero then as well? But why?

Comment: In your original problem, it was zero because of how a few details worked out once the Residue Theorem was applied. In the $|z|=\frac{1}{2}$ case, it is direct application of Cauchy's Theorem.

Answer (score 2):

The Laurent series of $f(z)=\frac{\sin(\pi z)}{(z-1)^5}$ at $z=1$ can be derived from the Laurent series of $g(z)=\frac{\sin(\pi(z+1))}{z^5}=-\frac{\sin(\pi z)}{z^5}$ at $z=0$. Since the last function is an even function, the residue at $z=0$ is zero, hence the original integral equals zero, too: no explicit computation is really needed.